# PreferenceActivity not showing twice on android

Tags: android

i've a PreferenceActivity which works perfectly the first time i launch it.

But if i close it ( with the back button ) and then i re open it ( through a menu click in the main activity ) then i get a black screen. There is no preferences at all..

I can't figure it out why it should not working.

It seems all the code is being called normally as the working one but no preferences are showing on the screen.

Did someone had the same behaviour ?

Comment: Well show us some code, maybe you are doing something wrong there.

Comment: I am also getting the same problem..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here is a sample project](http://github.com/commonsguy/cw-android/tree/master/Prefs/Dialogs/) that demonstrates the use of `PreferenceScreen` and does not suffer from this problem. Perhaps you can compare your implementation to this one to see where things differ.